# How to increase `maxTransactionSize` for Streaming Transactions in arangodb-php

Tags: php, arangodb, arangodb-php

The documentation says to pass as transaction-attribute (the call to `/begin`):

> maxTransactionSize: Transaction size limit in bytes. Honored by the RocksDB storage engine only.

I manage to do just that, despite the fact that the `php`-client ignores the attribute, by setting it manually before I hand the transaction-instance over to the handler:

```
 $trx->set('maxTransactionSize', $config['maxTransactionSize'])
```

This is `var_dump` of the transaction attributes (`$trx->attributes`) directly prior to the call to `begin`:

```php
includes/libs/arangodb/lib/ArangoDBClient/StreamingTransactionHandler.php:50:
array(2) {
  'collections' =>
    array(3) {
      'read' =>
       array(0) {
      }
      'write' =>
       array(0) {
      }
      'exclusive' =>
       array(1) {
         [0] =>
          string(7) "actions"
       }
    }
  'maxTransactionSize' =>
  int(536870912)
}
```

But the transaction fails with:

> error : AQL: aborting transaction because maximal transaction size limit of 134217728 bytes is reached (while executing)

What am I missing/doing wrong?

I tested this on 3.5.4 and 3.6.1, with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's prudent to read the whole documentation.  128MB is a hard upper limit for the size of a streaming transaction.

> A maximum lifetime and transaction size for stream transactions is enforced on the Coordinator to ensure that transactions cannot block the cluster from operating properly:
>
> Maximum idle timeout of 10 seconds between operations
>   Maximum transaction size of 128 MB per DB-Server
>   These limits are also enforced for stream transactions on single servers.

This means you have to use a js-transaction for queries that need more memory.  The arangodb-php client provides `Transaction.php` to wrap these on the client side, there's no need to write/extend a foxx-app -- at least, there are no limitations mentioned in the documentation of js-transactions (https://www.arangodb.com/docs/devel/http/transaction-js-transaction.html).

Edit: I re-implemented my case as js-transaction, and it completes unhindered.